# array.pop() function weird behavior

Tags: javascript, arrays, stack

Since documentation states that The pop method removes the last element from an array and returns that value to the caller. [from here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop)

But this statement below

```
arr=[1,2,3,4,5];
console.log(arr.pop());  //undefined
```

prints **undefined**

Do i always need to store the popped values and use it?? or there is any workaround.

**Update**
I am just getting "undefined" even in chrome console and in code if i am comparing arr.pop()== its returning true, i have attached the image below.

[image: This]

Comment: it should return 5.

Comment: it is returning 5 on chrome console

Comment: @manish-kumar I've updated the answer. Take a look!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this is happening.

[image]

`arr.pop()` is popping `5` and 5 is getting printed. And then
`undefined` is returned by `console.log()`.

[image]

Hope this answers your question.

UPDATE:

Make sure you check `Info` in the developers console

[image]

Comment: But it is also not reflecting in the code.I tried to print the popped element in the code. But yeah chrome console is printing it after checking info.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I will try to diagnose the code too.

Answer (score 0):

```js
(function() {
   arr=[1,2,3,4,5];
   console.log(arr.pop());
   console.log(arr.pop());
   console.log(arr.pop());
})()
```

It works fine here. Can you please update your code with whatever you have tried?.

Answer (score 0):

working fine.

```js
arr = [1,2,3,4,5];

console.log(arr.pop());
```